How to automatically restart a SSH tunnel?
I am working mostly from coffee shops, etc., and typically I use a tunnel to a database during that time.
I use a USB connection from iPhone to a Mac to provide the internet (I have unlimited 5G, and it's faster than the Wi-Fi connections from the shops)
The tunnel dies every time I take the phone away, etc. But the ssh app stays open and doesn't show any errors.
So I tried to use AutoSSH (How to reliably keep an SSH tunnel open?) but it just shows an error when the connection drops.
Is there a way to automatically restart the tunnel when the connectivity comes back?

What error are you getting specifically? Also, how did you install AutoSSH? Building from source or using a package manager like Homebrew?

I'm on MacOS and it was installed through Brew. On the laptop, if the connection dies, it doesn't display any error but the tunnel is gone by the time the connection is restarted. However, if I put the laptop to sleep and re-open it, I get lines of this: ssh: connect to host XXX port 22: Undefined error: 0
